# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '—1'

Tags: python

I've been trying to do a coding project that takes a screenshot from a math website, reads the words, extracts the numbers, and does the math for you.
Here's my code:

````
import cv2
import pyautogui as auto
import time
import pytesseract
import re

time.sleep(1)

# take screenshot using pyautogui
image = auto.screenshot("image2.png", region=(420,450, 600, 100))

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

img = cv2.imread("image2.png")

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

print(text[0:67])

pattern = "—?[0-9]?[0-9]"
List = re.findall(pattern, text)

An = int(re.findall(pattern, text)[0])
A1 = int(re.findall(pattern, text)[1])
A2 = int(re.findall(pattern, text)[2])

if A1 > A2:
    d = A2 - A1
elif A2 > A1:
    d = A1 - A2

Answer = A1 + (An - 1)(d)

print(Answer)

cv2.imshow("Img", img)```

:

Sorry for it being super sloppy I'm not very good at this. When I run the code I get this error message:
Find the 88th term of the arithmetic sequence 4, —1, —6,...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nicolas\PycharmProjects\homwork_folder\main.py", line 27, in <module>
    A2 = int(re.findall(pattern, text)[2])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '—1' :
````

It's almost like its not recognizing -1 or —1 as a integer.
Any suggestions or solutions. I'm super new to coding and its my first time doing a real project like this so anything said would be extremely helpful.
I have tried changing the way I convert the variables, I have done everything I can think of, and still I just can not fix the problem.

Comment: The first character of your pattern isn't "-".  If you type `hex(ord(pattern[0]))`, you'll see that it is an em-dash.   Python does not recognize em-dashes as the same as minus signs.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
text = text.replace('\u2014', '-')
```

to your code.  As mentioned in my comment above, tesseract is giving you em-dashes rather than minus signs.  And change your pattern to use the minus sign.